# How to detect user is touching the soft keyboard?

Tags: android, keyboard, android-softkeyboard

I want to determine the duration of user taps or swipes on the keyboard so that I can determine how long words/letters take a person to input using the soft keyboard.

Is there a way to detect only that the user has touched the keyboard (I don't care about what they are entering at this point)? I am using a TextWatcher to get the end of the tap/swipe, but I have not had any success getting the beginning of the tap/switch when the user first touches the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to detect only that the user has touched the keyboard

Write your own input method editor (a.k.a., soft keyboard) that contains your desired time recording. Then, convince users to switch to use your input method editor.

> I am using a TextWatcher to get the end of the tap/swipe

No, you are using a `TextWatcher` to detect changes to text in an `EditText`. Such changes *may* be from a user interacting with an input method editor. Or, they may be from the user using a physical keyboard. Or, they may be from action mode operations like cut and paste.